# Vue.js changed data is not showing on screen

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="start" @click="start_timer">
                {{ timerText }}
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Timer from 'easytimer.js';
    export default {
        name: 'GameStart',
        components: {

        },

        data() {
            return {
                timerText: "Start"
            }
        },

        methods: {
            start_timer() {

                var timer = new Timer();
                timer.start({countdown: true, startValues: {seconds: 4}});

                timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function () {
                    this.timerText = timer.getTimeValues()['seconds'].toString();
                    console.log(this.timerText);

                })

                timer.addEventListener('targetAchieved', function () {
                    console.log('complete');
                    this.timerText = "COMPLETE!!";

                });

            }
        },

        mounted() {
            // var timer = new Timer();
            // timer.start();

            // timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function () {
            //     console.log(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
            // });


        }
    }
</script>

<style>


    .parent {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;


    }

    .start {
        color: crimson;
        font-size: 50px;

    }

</style>
```

This is one of my component of my vue.js project.
I am trying to make mobile game with vue.js.
When user click the 'start' h1 tag, it run **start_timer** function.

I changed the variable **timerText** in the function **start_timer**, but the changed value (3, 2, 1) is not showing on the window.

What can I do for make three seconds counter in result?

Answer (score 1):

#### A common error with `this`

In Vue, we rely on `this` being a keyword that shares properties everywhere in the instance. Where it breaks down, however, is when we create a function with the keyword `function`.

Inside that function, the word `this` now refers to *that* function, not to the overall Vue component's `this`.

To avoid that problem, don't create the function with the `function` keyword: just use the fat-arrow notation, which does not create a new local `this`.

#### Fix

Change

```js
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function () {
                    this.timerText = timer.getTimeValues()['seconds'].toString();
                    console.log(this.timerText);

                })
```

to

```js
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated',  ()=> {
                    this.timerText = timer.getTimeValues()['seconds'].toString();
                    console.log(this.timerText);

                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is all about how to access the `this` inside a callback function.

As we are trying to access the component `data` objects. We should use arrow function as that don't provide their own this binding (it retains this value of the enclosing lexical context).

Hence, your callback functions should be change from a normal functions to an arrow functions.

```
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', () => {
  // You can access your data objects/properties here using `this` keyword.
})

timer.addEventListener('targetAchieved', () => {
  // You can access your data objects/properties here using `this` keyword.
});
```